# jquery table in Power BI envirnment

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am really new in the Microsoft Power BI.

I have search a lot how can i insert a data table in the power BI, envirment.

i have tested in the `init function` just to say hello world

```
    public init(options: VisualInitOptions): void {
        this.element = options.element;
        this.element.text('Hello World').css('font-size: 40px;')
    }
```

And it works fine !

So my question is

**How to insert a jquery datatable in a POWER BI envirment.**

Do anyone knows any answer or solution !
Thanks a lot in advanced ...